# Binary Tree- Level Order Traversal using Queue

Tags: data-structures, tree, queue, traversal

**Tree Traversal :: Level Order tree Traversal using Queue.**

**Give me a solution .**

> Level Order Tree Traversal
>
> we visit every node on a level before going to a lower level. This search is referred to as breadth-first search (BFS), as the search tree is broadened as much as possible on each depth before going to the next depth.

[Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

I want to traverse in a **Binary tree** in Level Order or u can say **BFS**
But i want to do it using **Queue**.

Thanks in advance for help.

---

Tree Structure ::

```
      1
     / \
   2     3
  / \
 4   5
```

Output Will be Like ::

1   2   3   4   5

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct queue
{
    struct node* info;
    struct queue* next;
};

struct node* NewNode(int data)
{
    struct node* root=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
    root->data=data;
    return root;
}


void enqueue(struct queue** que,struct node* newnode)
{
    struct queue* qnode = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    struct queue* temp=*que;
    qnode->info=newnode;
    qnode->next=NULL;
    if(*que==NULL)
    {
        *que=qnode;
        return;
    }
    while(temp!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
    temp->next=qnode;
}
struct node* dequeue(struct queue** que)
{
    if(que!=NULL){
        struct node* a=*que->info;
        *que=*que->next;
        return a;
    }
    return NULL;
}



void levelorder(struct node* root)
{

    struct queue* que=(struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    struct node* temp=root;
    while(temp)
    {
        printf("%d\t",temp->data);
        if(temp->left)
            enqueue(&que,temp->left);
        if(temp->right)
            enqueue(&que,temp->right);
        temp=dequeue(&que);
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct node* root=NewNode(1);
    root->left             = NewNode(2);
    root->right           = NewNode(3);
    root->left->left     = NewNode(4);
    root->left->right   = NewNode(5);

    levelorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not a question. This is a *question* and answer site – you'll need to do your own debugging, come to a hypothesis, and ask a *precise* question. Also, use the code formatting button in the question editor.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank u for ur reply.. can u please suggest me a way to implement binary tree level order traversal using queue?

Comment: no. Because, that is still not a *precise question*. You can do better than that, I promise! Get debugging, format your code, write a problem description, see my first comment.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok thanks .. i have done it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Binary Tree Level Order Traversal using Queue**

I declared here a queue of type structure. Here's the code ::

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};
struct Node* newnode(int data)
{
    struct Node* root=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
    root->data=data;
    return root;
}
struct Node* queue[100];
int rear=0;
int front=-1;
void enqueue(struct Node* node)
{
    queue[rear++]=node;
}
struct Node* dequeue()
{
    return queue[++front];
}
void levelOrder(struct Node* root)
{
    struct Node* temp=root;
    while(temp)
    {
        printf("%d\t",temp->data);
        if(temp->left)
            enqueue(temp->left);
        if(temp->right)
            enqueue(temp->right);
        temp=dequeue();
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct Node* root   =    newnode(2);
    root->left          =    newnode(3);
    root->right         =    newnode(4);
    root->left->left    =    newnode(7);
    root->left->left->left = newnode(1);

    levelOrder(root);
    return 0;
}
```